# google maps Javascript API not supported with IE9 can't load my map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, browser, internet-explorer-9

I use IE9 and I can't load my map. I have IE9 version for my broswer. 
When i'm trying to create my map, i have this error : "Google Maps API does not support this browser”.

I have tried with emulate in IE11 it works, but I don't want to use this way.
Or maybe just only change my .xls but I don't know how to do this because i'ts a frame in an other .xls (with IE9 necessarily).

So, how can I change my mainly web .xls IE11 without change all the application ?
Or how resolve this problem wihtout change IE version (keep our IE9 version).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var directionsPanel;
 var directions;
 //var directions2;
 var lastPoint;
 var trafficInfo;
 var geocoder;
 var place;
 var marker;
 var point;
 var adresse;
 var gdir;
 var htmls = [];
 //var directionsDisplay;
 var directionsDisplay=[];
 var objInfoWindowPrec;


 function loadmap() {
 //tableau des couleurs hexa
 var ArrayCouleur = new Array;

 //instanciation des elements du tableau
 var ArrayGDir = new Array;
 var indiceArray = 0;


 <!--var meta = document.createElement('meta');
  meta.httpEquiv = "X-UA-Compatible";
  meta.content = "IE=edge";
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);-->

   //implementation du tableau des codes hexa
   ArrayCouleur["1"] = "#FF4050";
   ArrayCouleur["3"] = "#FF40DA";
   ArrayCouleur["4"] = "#B540FF";
   ArrayCouleur["6"] = "#0014D0";
   ArrayCouleur["8"] = "#40E3FF";
   ArrayCouleur["11"] = "#1FFF50";
   ArrayCouleur["14"] = "#FFFF40";
   ArrayCouleur["16"] = "#FF9E06";
   ArrayCouleur["17"] = "#FF9F68";
   ArrayCouleur["18"] = "#FF0600";

var lat_center = 0;
                    var lng_center = 0;
                    var intZoom = 8;

                    lat_center = '<xsl:value-of select="/NewDataSet/Plateforme/geoloc_y"/>';
                    lng_center = '<xsl:value-of select="/NewDataSet/Plateforme/geoloc_x"/>';
 intZoom = 8;

 var pointCentre = new google.maps.LatLng(lat_center,lng_center);
 var myOption = {
 zoom: intZoom,
 center: pointCentre,
 panControl: true,
 zoomControl: true,
 mapTypeControl: true,
 scaleControl: true,
 streetViewControl: false,
 overviewMapControl: true,
 gestureHandling: 'greedy',
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 }
 /* Chargement de la carte  */

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOption);

  }
```

and in my xls :

```
<body onload="Base_Fenetre();loadmap();" onkeydown="RefreshMap(event)">
```

Comment: It is better you upgrade to IE 11 to make your code work with IE. There is no any other way available to make your code work with IE without upgrading to IE 11. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Internet Explorer 9 is [**officially NOT supported**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/browsersupport) by Google Maps Javascript API.

> Supported browsers:
>
> - The current version of Microsoft Edge (Windows)
> - **Internet Explorer 10
>     and 11** (Windows)
> - The current and previous version of Firefox (Windows,
>     macOS, Linux)
> - The current and previous version of Chrome (Windows,
>     macOS, Linux)
> - The current and previous version of Safari (macOS)

Comment: thanks, I have a question : I want to upgrade my IE but i don't know if I upgrade IE11 or Edge. IE11 will be die in next years. Egde or Mozilla ? Thanks a lot

Comment: If you're going to upgrade, just forget about IE since it's going to disappear. About Edge vs Mozilla this is opinion based and your choice alone. I prefer Google Chrome, but that's my own preference.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I think i will upgrade our version Edge. Microsoft is upgrading his new version of Egde with Chromium.